# Magento overwrite cart template

Tags: magento

I have issue with overwriting checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
That template is common for all simple, grouped and configurable items. Anyhow i tried below code. But it is not working.

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
        <reference name="checkout.cart">>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>mymodule/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>mymodule/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>mymodule/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
```

Can anyone please help me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding below code to the layout xml file;

```
<checkout_onepage_review translate="label">
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>testmodule/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>testmodule/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>testmodule/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_review>
```